# Which way is better between companion object and fun without a class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I know there isn't a static function in Kotlin, so I write two code in OkHttpService.kt and my.kt

I don't know which is better, could you tell me? Thanks!

**OkHttpService.kt**

```
class OkHttpService {

    companion object {
        fun httpGet(username: String, callback: Callback) {
            val fetchRepoUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/$username/repos?page=1&per_page=20"

            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val request = Request.Builder()
                    .url(fetchRepoUrl)
                    .build()

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback)
        }
    }
}
```

**my.kt**

```
fun OkHttpService_httpGet(username: String, callback: Callback) {
            val fetchRepoUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/$username/repos?page=1&per_page=20"

            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val request = Request.Builder()
                    .url(fetchRepoUrl)
                    .build()

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback)
```

Comment: Personal preference. Would you rather have a class-like namespace (OkHttpService) or just the usual pacakge-as-a-namespace? With the latter, you don't have the option of being explicit thus: `OkHttpService.httpGet()`.

Comment: Thanks!  which is better  throw away the name of fun ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Personally, I like everything in a class-like namespace, because it gives me the option of using it or static-importing it. But top-level functions are handy in some circumstances (e.g. when calling from kts / repl).

Comment: You could also declare OkHttpService itself as an object instead of a class.

Answer (score 4):

For scoping use a regular `object`, *not* `companion`:

```
object OkHttpService{
    fun httpGet(username: String, callback: Callback) {
        val fetchRepoUrl = "https://api.github.com/users/$username/repos?page=1&per_page=20"

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(fetchRepoUrl)
                .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you mean that the code ( companion object...) in OkHttpService.kt isn't a good way?

Comment: I meant that there shouldn't be a class if you don't create any instances of it. Companion objects has a very limited usage in Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks! but I was told there are more limited to use object, you may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46273453/which-way-is-better-if-i-hope-to-use-a-syntax-just-like-static-function-in-kotli

Comment: I think they meant that class scoping is rarely used in kotlin - packages should be enough. Also top level functions are negligibly more space-efficient than an object. But a companion object is also an object, so it is irrelevant here.